# Is it possible to store a variable or function value in the list of flutter(dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

One person in Stackover Flow gave me a hint about creating a learning page.
Using the list, save the necessary data, id and favorite variables, and call them to the index number.
I was creating a class to implement it.
However, I realized that variables could not be stored in the list...
Is there a way to save it?
And I don't make a separate class, but I'm going to make a list in the file with the following code.

But before, I heard that using global variables makes me stutter and it's bad for memory.

Shall we use "const"?
If not, wouldn't it be a problem how to make the class?
Of course, favorite variables cannot be used because they change from time to time.

```
const List<Function> fav_1 = [favoriteButton_0_01_01,.....];
```

1. Is it okay to use only the const list as a global variable instead of making a class?
2. Can I put variables in the list? Then, how?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is all over the place. Can you narrow it down to *one specific thing* you are having problems with? And explain in more details what you did so far, what you want to achieve and what you are stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

You can only put items with a matching type in the list.
if you define a list like "List" than only functions can be saved there.
if you define a list like "List" than only Integers can be saved there.

using const as a modifier will result in an unmodifiable list and so you won't be able to put anything in there.